# Updating a form value using redux-form-material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, redux-form

Using `material-ui@next` and `redux-form-material-ui@5.0.0-beta2` I've created a dialog and a form to display values that I need to edit. The form values are populated but I cannot figure out how to update the form field value on change. I've tried using `initialValues` for my form but aside from them showing up in `props` they don't appear to have an effect.

I'm aware that the code below is a bit of a dog's breakfast, I've been slapping bits and pieces in trying to get the stupid form field to update. I'm really not sure what the correct way to deal with populating forms in `React` is and I haven't found a good example online. Is there's an example online that someone is able to share that demonstrates a form loading data that uses `redux-form-material-ui` I'd be pretty happy to see it.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Field, reduxForm, formValueSelector } from 'redux-form'
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles'
import Button from 'material-ui/Button'
import Dialog, {
  DialogActions,
  DialogContent,
  DialogContentText,
  DialogTitle,
} from 'material-ui/Dialog'
import { TextField } from 'redux-form-material-ui'

const styles = theme => ({
  textField: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing.unit,
    marginRight: theme.spacing.unit,
  },
  commentField: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing.unit,
    marginRight: theme.spacing.unit,
    paddingRight: theme.spacing.unit,
  },
})

const propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  open: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  commentData: PropTypes.object,
  body: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  onCancel: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  onSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
}

class CommentDialog extends Component {

  renderAuthorField = () => {
    const { classes, comments, selectedCommentId } = this.props

    const data = (comments) ? comments[selectedCommentId] : undefined
    const author = data ? data.author : ''

    return (
      <TextField
        margin="normal"
        id="author"
        className={classes.textField}
        label="Author"
        type="text"
        fullWidth
        disabled={true}
        value={author}
      />
    )
  }

  renderBodyField = ({ input, children, ...custom }) => {
    const { classes, comments, selectedCommentId } = this.props

    const data = (comments) ? comments[selectedCommentId] : undefined
    const body = data ? data.body : ''

    return (
      <TextField
        margin="normal"
        id="body"
        label="Comment"
        className={classes.commentField}
        type="text"
        multiline={true}
        rows={4}
        rowsMax={8}
        fullWidth
        value={body}
        onChange={this.updateBody}
      />
    )
  }

  updateBody = (event) => {
    // can't get this to do anything
  }

  render() {
    const {
      open,
      handleSubmit,   // This is added by redux-form
      onSubmit,
      onCancel,
      comments,
      selectedCommentId,
    } = this.props

    const data = (comments) ? comments[selectedCommentId] : undefined

    return (
      <Dialog
        open={open}
        onClose={onCancel}
        aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title"
      >
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">
            'Edit Comment'
          </DialogTitle>
          <DialogContent>
            <DialogContentText>
              'Modify the post content.'
            </DialogContentText>
            <Field
              name="author"
              component={this.renderAuthorField}
            />
            <Field
              name="body"
              component={this.renderBodyField}
            />
          </DialogContent>
          <DialogActions>
            <Button onClick={onCancel} color="primary">
              Cancel
            </Button>
            <Button type="submit" color="primary">
              Submit
            </Button>
          </DialogActions>
        </form>
      </Dialog>
    )
  }
}

CommentDialog.propTypes = propTypes

const selector = formValueSelector('comment')

CommentDialog = connect(state => ({
  comment: selector(state, 'comment'),
  comments: state.comments.commentsByPost,
  selectedCommentId: state.comments.selectedCommentId,
}))(CommentDialog)

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'comment',
  fields: ['author', 'body'],
  initialValues: { author: '', body: '' }
})(withStyles(styles)(CommentDialog))
```

Comment: can you clarify something. in your `updateBody` function. are you implying it is not even being called? or it *is* being called but you're not sure what to do inside that function to actually change the values

Comment: It does get called but even if I use setState the form value never changes after I've set it with a value={state.someValue}

Comment: If you want to change a form field you should call `this.props.change(<fieldName>, <fieldValue>);` inside your `updateBody`. Have you tried already?

Comment: @Dario I hadn't tried that, but I did and it didn't work. I assume for what I've got that would be `this.props.change('body', event.target.value).

Comment: Do you get the right value in `event.target.value`? What is `this` inside `updateBody`? I think you are missing to `bind(this)` your `updateBody` call. Maybe you need to write the constructor of your component and inside have `this.updateBody = this.updateBody.bind(this);`

Comment: I wasn't able to find a solution using `redux-form-material-ui` and just ended up using basic forms and custom styles. I'm still not sure how to do it with this library after following what's in the documentation.